# OSMC installation fail - cannot boot it with three micro sd card

Tags: boot, osmc

I tried since several hours installing OSMC on RPi2 but after many trials I don't get it booting. I would like to investigate further.

I've tried with three micro sd cards and severals methods, here the description.

**Material**

*Micro SD :*

```
 - Kingston HC I(1) 8Gb class 10  
 - Lexar HC 16Gb class 6   
 - Sandisk Extreme 8Gb Class 10
```

*Utilities used :*

```
 - Startup Disk Image (ubuntu tool)  
 - unetbootin  
 - dd (linux shell)   
 - restore disk image - disks utilities on ubuntu  
 - OSMC installer utility for linux
```

I use SD adapter to connect the micro-sd to my laptop. In this process, I've used 2 different.

None of this combination works.

I tried OSMC image OSMC_TGT_rbp2_20160502.img and previous.
I tried OpenElec image OpenELEC-RPi2.arm-6.0.3.img

Check the md5 of image and none is corrupted.

**Installing Raspbian on sdcard works well. Boot normal.**

I don't know how to do more to investigate further or make it work.

Any guess or good tips ?

Comment: What do you see when booting? Which if any of the LEDs on the Pi light up?

Answer (score -1):

When using the OSMC installer, try selecting the Raspberry Pi 1/Zero as the OS as that worked for me.

Have a look at this forum: https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/will-not-boot-up-when-inserted-osmc-sdcard-into-raspberry-pi-2/4325/18

Comment: If you read through the forum thread you linked to, you will see that the problem in that case was either a bad powersupply or SD card.